# Let $V=\{f \in X \mid f(0)=f(1)=0\}$ be a linear subspace of $C[0,1]$. Show $(V,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is Banach.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you please confirm if my proof is correct and if not show where I went wrong. Thanks!

Let ${f_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $V$ then $f_n(x)$ is a real number for each $x\in [0,1]$
Hence ${f_n(x)}$ converges to $f(x)$ say by the completeness of the Reals. So
$$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x) \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow \infty \mbox{ for each } x$$
So the limit of $f_n(0)=f_n(1)\rightarrow f(0)=f(1)=0$ so $f\in V$. So every Cauchy sequence in V converges to a function in $V \Rightarrow$ $V$ is Banach.

Sorry for the sloppy notation, new to LaTeX!

Comment: It's not actually LaTeX; it's MathJax.  LaTeX is used for whole documents, not just mathematical notation.

Comment: You still need o prove that the limiting function $f$ is continuous.

Comment: There is nothing wrong above, just incomplete. You can either use the fact that $C[0,1]$ is complete or show that $f$ is continuous directly using uniform convergence.

Comment: Hi, how do I know that $\|f_n-f\|\rightarrow 0 $?

Answer (score 3):

A closed subspace of a complete space is complete. All you need to do is verify that $V$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$. But $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0$ implies $f_n \to f$ pointwise. So if $f_n \in V$ converges to a function $f \in C[0,1]$ then $f_n(0) \to f(0)$ and $f_n(1) \to f(1)$. Thus $f \in V$ and $V$ is closed.

Comment: Hi, how do I know $\|f_n-f\|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: It is a conditional statement: if $\|f_n - f\| \to 0$ then $f \in V$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi_
t(f) = f(t)$ and since $|\phi_t(f)| \le \|f\|$ we see that $\phi_t$ is continuous. Then $V = \ker \phi_1 \cap \ker \phi_0$ and so is a closed
subset of a complete metric space, hence complete.

Alternatively, suppose $f_n \in V$ is Cauchy. We have $f_n \to f \in C[0,1]$, and since $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(1) = 0$ for all $n$ we have $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and so $f \in V$.